# when i 'm trying to access google map in lightbox iframe i'm getting Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, lightbox

when i 'm trying to access google map in lightbox iframe i'm getting Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL  Domains, protocols and ports must match.
my code is

```
<a href="#inline_demo86871" rel="prettyPhoto[inline]" onclick="response_map(86871)"><strong>Map It</strong></a>
```

Here i'm using pretty photo for popup lightbox depends on response_map id it loads the google map on popup.
everythng is working fine but. i'm getting the error when i'm trying to load map by clicking the anchor tag.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://mysite.com from frame with URL http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=address&output=embed. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read that tutorial: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/blog/2010/09/28/tutorial-opening-custom-content-in-prettyphoto/

It will help you figure out how to open custom content (Google Maps) in prettyPhoto.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Google disabled the ability to access it's sites using an iframes (See http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/10/23/1949227/google-not-reciprocating-on-iframe-usage)